# Sliding div off-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m having a little trouble with this template: basically, I’m trying to add functionality where if you click a box it will expand sliding the other ones off-screen, but instead sliding the `div` off-screen it’s disappearing completely.

Here is what I have so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rw7rhe4p/).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    var isopened = $(this).attr("isopen");
    if (isopened == "true") {
      $(this).css("position", "relative").css("width", $(this).attr("data-ow"));
      $(this).attr("isopen", "false");
    }
    else {
      $(this).attr("data-ow", $(this).css("width"));
      $(this).css("position", "relative").css("width", "40%");
      $(this).attr("isopen", "true");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  width: 13.33333333%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.box:first-of-type {
  width: 29.0%;
  background-color: orange;
}
.box:last-of-type {
  width: 29.0%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

What I ultimately want is when one of the boxes is clicked it expands and instead of the entire `div` being hidden only the part which is off-screen is hidden:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might like this [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) solution as you can do what you want without usign any jQuery/JS. Pure CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
#container > div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  transition:min-width 0.2s ease;
  outline:0;
}
#container > div:focus {
  min-width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div tabindex="0" style="background-color:blue"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" style="background-color:orange"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" style="background-color:white"></div>
  <div tabindex="0" style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

I used [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) to give me the ability to use the `:focus` selector.

Comment: you sir are a fking legend :)

Comment: Similar trick but with jQuery [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dsk6pkrd/). Only advantage of jQuery is you have little control to do some extra processing, like toggling state of a div.